# Error while importing http packages in android studio 2.1

Tags: java, android, apache, http, android-studio

Hey there I am importing few http packages for communication but I am getting error in these lines:

```
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
```

I am using latest android studio. Any help regarding importing these packages?
I came to know that http packages are deprecated for android. To use above mentioned packages which package should I import ?
Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: After building gradle i am getting this: Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: @PrerakSola I have compiled gradle adding these two lines in dependencies :compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5' . But still I am getting red lines and warnings.

Comment: Try by replacing your dependencies in build.gradle with `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1' `

Comment: @PrerakSola But I think these are the old versions of https don't you think that will affect the app performance ? Because of may be these versions have some drawback.

Comment: @PrerakSola Nope still not fixed it says the same warning and the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Santosh Yes httpclient has been deprecated in Android 5.1 and has been removed from the Android SDK in Android 6.0. You can read about this in more detail on this link

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

To fix your problem you just need to add this line in android tag in build.gradle file `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`
Hope this helps.

Comment: This link is also very useful https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html